# "overweening swagger" vs. "overweening pretension"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, gre

I came across the following two-blank text-completion question while
preparing for the GRE:

> ①  ______ by circumstance, the entrepreneur once known for his overweening
>   ②  _______ was now seen by others as the possessor of a broken spirit and
>   timid demeanor.

The options for blank ①  are:

- unaffected
- humbled
- exalted

The options for blank ②  are:

- pretension
- swagger
- wealth

I was able to pick *humbled* for blank ①  easily because it was the only one
that made sense in the context of the sentence (which was the right
answer).

I went with *swagger* for blank ②  because I thought it was a good
substitute for *arrogance*, but the correct answer mentioned is
*pretension*. According to the definition given for *pretension* which is
*a claim or assertion of a claim to something*, I feel it doesn’t quite fit
in.

Can someone please explain the difference?

Comment: I would have expected _pride_ to follow _overweening_; of the alternatives provided, _pretension_ is the nearest. There is another definition along the lines of _trying to impress people_.

Comment: I recommend changing the titles of your GRE questions to include the words in contention. That will make it more searchable for future users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at examples of usage of *overweening* [at 
Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/overweening), you will see
that it is primarily used with such words and phrases as

> *pride       confidence       ambition       sense of self-importance       arrogance       hubris*

What they have in common is that they describe a psychological trait, an 
**inner** disposition.

*Swagger*, on the other hand, usually denotes **external** manifestations of such dispositions:

> *an arrogantly self-confident **way of walking** : an **act** or instance of swaggering*
>            *arrogant or conceitedly self-assured **behavior***
>            *ostentatious **display** or **bravado***
>  
>                 [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swagger)

In contrast, *pretension* means *vanity* 
[(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretension),
and so it also refers to an inner attribute. This is why it is a better
fit.

Comment: I've just realised that this doesn't become 'good' until correct attributions rather than just covert links are given. Even a good ship needed a ha'porth of tar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks to tchrist!

Comment: Sounds vaguely irreverent. tchrist doesn't claim to be infallible; he even acknowledges that the subjunctive may be largely Old Testament in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

Was going to suggest *ambition* as the best fit, until I saw the list of allowed alternatives.

Of those *pretension* is the only one that feels satisfactory in context. You need an attribute of character, which rules out 'wealth' and 'swagger' is more suggestive of behaviour than personal nature.

Comment: Not a bad answer, Chaconia, but @linguisticum gives a (good_ one.